# Unable to find element via XPath with C#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, xpath, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to find and click on the following element:

---

```
<input type="checkbox" data-columna="colAusenciaDia" data-bind="attr: { 'data-AlumnoId': $data.AlumnoId }" data-alumnoid="9f900e5a-3325-4179-9c6f-a7bc008988c0"/>
```

---

Inside this code:

---

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<tr data-bind="attr: { Id: $data.AlumnoId }" id="9f900e5a-3325-4179-9c6f-a7bc008988c0" class=""> 
  <td class="bkgAzul text-center" style="color: #fff; width: 20px;"> 
    <span data-bind="text: $root.ObtenerContador()">1</span> 
  </td>  
  <td width="190px"> 
    <span data-bind="text: $data.Apellido1 + ' ' + $data.Apellido2 + ', ' + $data.AlumnoNombre">Ap_Alumno_0AñosA_1 , Nb_Alumno_0AñosA_1</span> 
  </td>  
  <td class="text-center" colspan="1" width="40px"> 
    <!-- ko if: ($data.DiaJustificado &&  $data.DiaJustificadoMismaPersona) || $data.IncidenciaDiaria  -->  
    <!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado &&  $data.DiaJustificadoMismaPersona == false && $data.IncidenciaDiaria==false  -->  
    <!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado == false && $data.IncidenciaDiaria == false -->  
    <input type="checkbox" data-columna="colAusenciaDia" data-bind="attr: { 'data-AlumnoId': $data.AlumnoId }" data-alumnoid="9f900e5a-3325-4179-9c6f-a7bc008988c0"/>  
    <!-- /ko --> 
  </td>  
  <!-- ko if: $root.TienePermisoJustificar() -->  
  <td class="text-center" width="40px"> 
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado &&  $data.DiaJustificadoMismaPersona == true -->  
    <!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado &&  $data.DiaJustificadoMismaPersona == false -->  
    <!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado == false && $data.IncidenciaDiaria == false -->  
    <input type="checkbox" data-columna="colJustificadaDia" data-bind="attr: { 'data-AlumnoId': $data.AlumnoId }" disabled="disabled" data-alumnoid="9f900e5a-3325-4179-9c6f-a7bc008988c0"/>  
    <!-- /ko -->  
    <!-- ko if: $data.DiaJustificado == false && $data.IncidenciaDiaria == true -->  
    <!-- /ko --> 
  </td>  
  <!-- /ko --> 
</tr>
```

---

For that, I am using the following code:

---

```
// where nombreAlumno is "Ap_Alumno_0AñosA_1 , Nb_Alumno_0AñosA_1"
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(text(), '" + nombreAlumno + "')]/ancestor::tr/td/input[@data-columna = 'colAusenciaDia']")).Click();
```

---

However the element is not being found. The problem is I am able to find it in a XPath tester like http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

I have no idea where the problem lies. Any help is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: Why have you written such a complex xpath? this is working for me "//input[@data-columna = 'colAusenciaDia']"

Comment: Hi, @Pradeephebbar the html code is only a snippet of a dynamic table with around 40 rows.

As the table is dynamic I cannot do it another way without a `StaleElementException`, that's why I use the nombreAlumno variable to find the row I am looking for.

Comment: Can you add the url of the webpage? What is the exception when the element is not found?

Comment: Is it in an IFRAME? Have you tried adding a wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem lied in how the element's text is shown:

As you can see here:

---

```html
<span data-bind="text: $data.Apellido1 + ' ' + $data.Apellido2 + ', ' + $data.AlumnoNombre">Ap_Alumno_0AñosA_1  , Nb_Alumno_0AñosA_1</span>
```

---

The text of the span contains two whitespaces just before the comma: `Ap_Alumno_0AñosA_1  ,`

However, the text in will appear with only one whitespace `Ap_Alumno_0AñosA_1 , Nb_Alumno_0AñosA_1`

It seems to be a problem with `knockout.js`

In any case, I fixed it by changing the way the driver looks for the element:

---

```cs
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(text(), '" + nombreAlumno.Substring(nombreAlumno.IndexOf(",")) + "')]/ancestor::tr/td/input[@data-columna = 'colAusenciaDia']")).Click();
```

---

This way the code will search for a `<span>` which contains only the text until the `,`

Thanks everybody for your input.

Answer (score 1):

To locate the element :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-columna="colAusenciaDia" data-bind="attr: { 'data-AlumnoId': $data.AlumnoId }" data-alumnoid="9f900e5a-3325-4179-9c6f-a7bc008988c0"/>
```

And invoke `click()` you can use the following line of code :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,5,100));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(., '" + nombreAlumno + "')]//following::td[2]/input"))).Click();
```

You can get more granular and use the attribute `data-columna` value which is set as **colAusenciaDia** as follows :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,5,100));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(., '" + nombreAlumno + "')]//following::td/input[@data-columna='colAusenciaDia']"))).Click();
```

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I've tried both solutions (even changing `.` for `text()` just to make sure and none of them seem to fix the problem.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: @elgato Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi again @DebanjanB,

I tried your solution modifying it a little:

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumHelper.GetWebDriver(), new TimeSpan(0, 5, 100));

    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(., '" + nombreAlumno + "')]//following::td[2]/input"))).Click();
    SeleniumHelper.GetWebDriver().FindElement(By.XPath("//td/span[contains(text(), '" + nombreAlumno + "')]//following::td[2]/input")).Click();

However, the execution failed with `Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock'`, even though the element was visible.

Comment: @elgato Well, I don't have a visibility to `SeleniumHelper` Class and `GetWebDriver` method. Check that method for deadlock. Else our code is perfect.